# lru_cache that saves for all class instances

Tags: python-3.x, class, caching, properties, functools

Is there any way I can `lru_cache` a `@property` at class level in python so that even when returning that calculated property with the same values for another class instance, the property will not be recalculated, rather pulled from cache. I want to achieve something like the below:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
         self.num1 = num1
         self.num2 = num2

    @property
    @lru_cache
    def sum(self):  #this can even be a class method if needed, I don't really care
       return self.num1 + self.num2


    t1 = SomeClass(2,3)
    t1.sum
    >> 5          #calculating


    t2 = SomeClass(2,3)
    t2.sum
    >> 5          #returning cache from t1, NOT calculating
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `methodtools.lru_cache`

```py
from methodtools import lru_cache

called = 0

class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2

    @lru_cache()
    @classmethod
    def _sum(cls, num1, num2):
        global called
        called += 1
        return num1 + num2

    @property
    def sum(self):
        return self._sum(self.num1, self.num2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert called == 0

    t1 = SomeClass(2, 3)
    print(t1.sum)
    assert called == 1

    t2 = SomeClass(2, 3)
    print(t2.sum)
    assert called == 1
```

Answer (score 3):

So I found a solution, though not using `funtools.lru_cache`, but `ring`. From what I've read, `lru_cache` can't do this, but if someone knows a solution using `lru_cache`, feel free to post it, and I will mark it as the correct answer.

```
import ring 

class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
         self.num1 = num1
         self.num2 = num2

    @ring.dict({})
    @property
    def sum(self): 
       return self.num1 + self.num2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this could be done using an variable to holds already executed calculations.
I've reworked your code a little bit, so let's take a look at it.
Consider you have the following code:

```
CACHED_VALUES = {}

class SomeClass:
  def __init__(self, num1, num2):
    self.num1 = num1
    self.num2 = num2
    self.pair = '{},{}'.format(num1,num2)
    if self.pair not in CACHED_VALUES.keys():
      print('Calculating from init...')
      CACHED_VALUES[self.pair] = self.sum
    else:
      print('Already stored... Getting the values from cache...')

  @property
  def sum(self):  #this can even be a class method if needed, I don't really care
      return self.num1 + self.num2


t1 = SomeClass(2,3)
print(t1.sum)

t2 = SomeClass(2,3)
print(t2.sum)

print('This is new instance.')
t3 = SomeClass(2,3)
print(t3.sum)
```

Firstly I've created `CACHED_VALUES` dictionary that empty (for now). Please note that it's declared outside of the class.
Secondly I've created `self.pair` variable that holds represents the both numbers as string, delimited by comma. The reason of doing that is because you **cannot have** **lists as** **dictionary keys**. That's why we concatenate both numbers into string.

If we apply this approach, the `CACHED_VALUES` dictionary will be updated as follows:

```
CACHED_VALUES = {}
t1 = SomeClass(2,3)
print(CACHED_VALUES)
>> {'2,3': 5}
```

Now about the `__init__` method.

I've added if condition to checks whether the `CACHED_VALUES` dictionary already contains calculated value. If not - function is executed and the returned value is saved to the dictionary. If it exists - then we get the already calculated value, omitting the function execution.

Below  you can see the reworked code and its output:

```
   CACHED_VALUES = {}

class SomeClass:
  def __init__(self, num1, num2):
    self.num1 = num1
    self.num2 = num2
    self.pair = '{},{}'.format(num1,num2)
    if self.pair not in CACHED_VALUES.keys():
      print('Calculating from init...')
      CACHED_VALUES[self.pair] = self.sum
    else:
      print('Already stored... Getting the values from cache...')

  @property
  def sum(self):  #this can even be a class method if needed, I don't really care
      return self.num1 + self.num2


print('[X]Creating first instance')
t1 = SomeClass(2,3)
print(t1.sum)

print('[X]Creating second instance')
t2 = SomeClass(2,3)
print(t2.sum)

print('[X]This is instance with different values.')
t3 = SomeClass(5,7)
print(t3.sum)

print('[X]This is second instance with different values.')
t4 = SomeClass(5,7)
print(t4.sum)



# OUTPUT:
[X]Creating first instance
Calculating from init...
5
[X]Creating second instance
Already stored... Getting the values from cache...
5
[X]This is instance with different values.
Calculating from init...
12
[X]This is second instance with same values.
Already stored... Getting the values from cache...
12
```

Comment: I mean that is a workaround. I have however found another solution with @ring.dict({}).

Answer (score 1):

I am adding second answer, because I don't have enough reputation to add comment to your answer.

You can check the following code snippets (taken from https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html):

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

>>> [fib(n) for n in range(16)]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610]

>>> fib.cache_info()
CacheInfo(hits=28, misses=16, maxsize=None, currsize=16)
```

or

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=32)
def get_pep(num):
    'Retrieve text of a Python Enhancement Proposal'
    resource = 'http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-%04d/' % num
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(resource) as s:
            return s.read()
    except urllib.error.HTTPError:
        return 'Not Found'

>>> for n in 8, 290, 308, 320, 8, 218, 320, 279, 289, 320, 9991:
...     pep = get_pep(n)
...     print(n, len(pep))

>>> get_pep.cache_info()
CacheInfo(hits=3, misses=8, maxsize=32, currsize=8)
```

Answer (score 0):

A problem with the here given solution is that you have no access to self because it is a classmethod, cumbersome or do not work for derived classes, i.e. the `cls` argument changes for the key.

[`cachetools`](https://pypi.org/project/cachetools/) offers some nice options.

First `cachetools.keys.mehodkey(self, *args, **kwargs) -> hash` creates a hashvalue ignoring the first parameters `self`, `class` which solves the inheritance problem.
Using `cachetools.keys.mehodkey` *used the first parameter*.

Further it can be chosen if the cache is one global object, one cache per function, or a cache managed by the instance, i.e. you have all the cases n:1, 1:n, n:n.

#### Global Cache

```
from cachetools import cached, cachedmethod, LRUCache

CACHE = LRUCache(maxsize=100)

class A:
    
    @cached(CACHE) # key is (self, arg)
    def entry_for_instance(self, arg):
        ...

    @classmethod
    @cached(CACHE)  # key is (cls, arg) #NOTE not shared with child classes!
    def shared_for_A(cls, arg):  
       ...

    @cached(CACHE, key=cachetools.keys.mehodkey)  ->
    def entry_for_instance(self, arg):
        # key is (arg)
        # shared with all functions of the same signature
        # Hint: use cachetools.keys.typedkey to make typesafe
        ...
```

#### Instance managed

Note that cachedmethod expects a `callable(self)->cache` instead of an cache-object as first argument.

```
class B:

    def __init__(self, cachesize):
        self.cache = LRUCache(maxsize=cachesize)

    @cachedmethod(lambda self: self.cache) # determined by instance.attribute
    def entry_for_instance(self, arg):
        ...

    # - class level -

    CLASS_CACHE = LRUCache(maxsize=100) # needs to be set up for all caches

    @classmethod
    @cachedmethod(lambda cls: cls.CLASS_CACHE)
    def entry_of_class(cls, arg):
       # cls is ignored for the key. Child classes can overwrite CLASS_CACHE if wanted.

    @cachedmethod(lambda self: self.__class__.CLASS_CACHE)
    def entry_of_class_from_instance(self, arg):
       # if self is needed but it should be shared
       # Child classes can overwrite again.
```

Other examples are in the documentation

#### Per function cache

Here I came up with the following decorator. Using `sharedcache` allows sharing on a function level across all instances, including those of child classes.
Advantage no global or class attributes need to be set up.

This decorator is like a mix of `cached` and `cachedmethod`.

```
# --- Decorators ---
# simple variant
def sharedcache(func):
    return cache({}, key=cachetools.keys.mehodkey)(func) # cache itself is a decorating function

# flexible variant which allows arguments and specifying the type of cache object.
def sharedcache(cache_factory : callable = functools.partial(LRUCache, maxsize=100), # creates a new instance
                key = cachetools.keys.mehodkey, 
                lock=None, 
                **factory_kwargs):
    def wrapper(func):
        return cached(cache_factory(**factory_kwargs), key=key)(func)
    return wrapper
```

By specifying as cache a callable a cache can be bound

```
class C:

    @sharedcache 
    def get_instance(self, num):

    @classmethod # if you want to share a classmethod
    @sharedcache
    def get_class(cls, arg):

    @staticmethod
    @functools.cache
    def get_static(arg):
        # for static methods once can more easily fall back to functools
```